# Messageboxes gone crazy

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a user control and i put a messagebox line in a timer to test some functionality. The good news is that the test told me exactly what i expected to hear, the bad news is that the messageboxes are spawning every 1ms even while the program isnt running. I removed the messagebox spawn line from the code from outside VS but I suspect the design mode has a compiled version of that control somewhere and is running the code. I cant recompile a new version since the messageboxes wont let me touch VS.. help?

Comment: CTRL+ALT+DEL is my suggestion...

Comment: the problem isnt closing the program, its getting back to writing my code. Every time i load up the project the messageboxes start spawning again.

Comment: Well, edit the project with Notepad or something and comment out the control so it doesn't get created at design time.

Comment: as stated i did that already

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, i deleted the obj folder in the project. Needs a rebuild before design mode is functional again but works ok now.